# inotifywait running daemon mode giving error Couldn't initialize inotify

Tags: linux, inotifywait

I am running inotifywait (inotify-tools-3.14-1) in the daemon mode, however, it gave the following error and no watches are established.  Also, since it is within the while loop, there were many inotifywait daemon processes created.

I have no such problem if running with --monitor instead of --daemon.  Can someone help fixing it?  Thanks a lot.

"*Couldn't initialize inotify.  Are you running Linux 2.6.13 or later, and was the
CONFIG_INOTIFY option enabled when your kernel was compiled?  If so,
something mysterious has gone wrong.  Please e-mail radu.voicilas@gmail.com
 and mention that you saw this message.*"

Below is the code:

```
while true  # run indefinitely
do
  inotifywait --daemon --outfile /tmp/daemon.log --event close_write --format '%w%f %e %T' --timefmt '%F %T' $folder |  while read eventInfo
     do
        call_another_fun $eventInfo
        break
     done
   done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are too many inotify processes running in background, I also get this "Couldn't initialize inotify..." error message.
A `pkill inotify` solved this.

Comment: I have don't have any `inotify` processes running, and I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

You should increase the maximum amount of inotify instances.

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=2048
```

On my Desktop System the default of 128 Instances was to low for a few file-browsers, IDEs and electron apps. All of them have multiple inotify instances.

To make this permanent, add this line into `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.inotify.max_user_instances=2048
```

Comment: I ran into this same issue within a container. I had to apply this on my host OS.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling

```
apt-get remove inotify-tools
```

Then reinstalling

```
apt-get install inotify-tools
```

resolved it for me. Between uninstalling and reinstalling I happened to have also run `sudo apt autoremove` but I doubt that it was part of the solution.